# AppCompat ActionBar Background Color

Tags: android-layout, android-activity, android-actionbar, android-styles, android-actionbar-compat

I have this style.xml inside my Android app:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<style name="OrangeTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle" tools:ignore="NewApi">@style/OrangeTheme.OrangeActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
</style>

<style name="OrangeTheme.OrangeActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/orange</item>
    <item name="background">@color/orange</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@color/orange</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@color/orange</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/Theme.MyAppTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.MyAppTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

I have searched StackOverflow and Google, but nothing helped. I wasn't able to change the `ActionBar` background color.

Inside my `MainActivity`, I use this code:

```
 public void restoreActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
}
```

I tried not to use AppCompat, but then my name has a lot of errors. It extends `ActionBarActivity`. If I change it to `FragmentActivity` I can't use `getSupportActionBar()` and without it my `getActionBar()`, is always `null`.

```
minSdkVersion 19
targetSdkVersion 21
```

So right now I am not able to change it. I tried renaming the parent of my style theme. I tried using `andrioud:background` and `background`. The only thing that is changing is when I use another parent like
`Theme.App.Compat.Light` or `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`.

Does someone have an idea, how I could be able to change the colors and other stuff, on runtime?

Comment: Hope this helps! 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23155637/change-background-color-of-the-action-bar-using-appcompat

Comment: Already tried those, didnt work

Answer (score 0):

With new AppCompat-v7 (v21) you can use new color theming attributes. See [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html).

Or alternatively you have to use `<item name="actionBarStyle">` property (without prefix *android*).

Answer (score 0):

To use background color with AppCompat, you need to also define the item name without the `android:` attribute.

for example:

```
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:background">@color/action_bar_background</item>

    <item name="background">@color/action_bar_background</item> //<--background item without the android attribute
</style>
```

and then in your custom theme do the same thing for the custom actionbar style:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>
```