# Can't change background colour of ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm trying to change the background colour of my Android app, but I'm not being able to. I've searched through a lot of posts but none solution solved mine.

Here's mine styles.xml:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">#ff0000</item>
</style>


</resources>
```

As you can see, I'm just trying to set the bar to red.
Here's my manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MenuActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

The theme is properly set, as you can see. And just so you can see, here's my gradle:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    ...
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 21



}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

So, even though this looks alright, it is not setting my ActionBar to red. I tried following a lot of guides (including the official one) and I've done everything as they say. What am I missing? Thank you for your patience in advance :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you are using the `AppCompat` library, you should handle older android versions too (just like it was when using the `ActionBarSherlock` library):

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/red</item>
        <item name="background">@android:color/red</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

The items without the android namespace are for styling the appcompat actionbar used on older android versions.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23156002/506879) for further reference.

You should also check, that you probably have more `styles.xml` files generated for various screen sizes and sdk version.

You may want to add your `ActionBar` style declarations to these other styles too: it looks like your test device uses another one, not the default.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. I only have one styles.xml, situated inside the "values" folder. The other "values" folder that I have is "values-w820dp" that only has "dimens.xml" inside :(

Comment: It seems that you are using an older android version for testing, please see my answer on how to proceed to make it work

Comment: It worked! The only change I had to make to your answer was to change the colour in the

    <item name="background">#ff0000</item>

It doesn't accept HEX as an argument. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I'm glad I could help. I'm going to update the answer based on your note, so others could learn from that too. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you a lot. I search all the net and try all solution but just this work. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style name="Demo_Theme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/actionBG</item>
    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/actionBG</item>
</style>

<style name="actionBG" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/test_bg_color</item>
    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="background">@color/test_bg_color</item>
</style>
```

This should work fine.