# Notification bar background doesn't change using appcompat library

Tags: java, android, android-appcompat

I have used this tutorial [Making materialdesign app](http://www.android4devs.com/2014/12/how-to-make-material-design-app.html#comment-form) using appcompact and it works great.But I have a problem with style.when I run application the notification bars background should change to `colorPrimaryDark` like this image
[image]

but it does not change for me..Can you please give me some hints how to fix that?

I have tested this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23155637/change-background-color-of-the-action-bar-using-appcompat) but it does not work 
I have tested it on android 4.4.4 on sony Xperia z2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unfortunately there is no support of that functionality for previous versions of Android through the support library. (Anything before 5.0 won't work).

Comment: Thanks very much,But I have seen some applications that runs on my phone and they have changed the statusbar background..I'll attach a screen shot to my question

Comment: I'll check it out, but they do not use the support library for sure

Comment: I've found out a solution for your issue: check out this library https://github.com/jgilfelt/SystemBarTint it should help you setting the bar in translucent mode so that you can draw the color underneath.. Also if you like my answer remember to accept the question, not just upvote it, it helps me gain reputation.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have this on pre-lollipop versions.

Answer (score 0):

Yup! It's true that you cannot set the color of status bar in pre lollipop devices. But I have seen colorful status bar in some of the pre lollipop devices like Xiaomi's Redmi Note 4G.

Image Link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6MO1.png

This can be done by setting the status bar in translucent mode.
Hope this was helpful :D