# Android : API 19 : Change default blue color "Theme.AppCompat.Light"

Tags: android

I want to change the default blue color of this theme to my custom color.
As you can see the `ListView` Color is blue. Same goes for  `AlertDialogs` and other built in features. I want to change this default blue color to my own color.

[image]

**Update my style.xml**

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/DarkYellow</item>

       <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/DarkYellow</item>
</style>
```

**Image**
[image]

Comment: Any Help Andorid Gurus  ?

Answer (score 2):

In your styles.xml in values folder you should define the following colors:

```
<style name="Theme.default" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/grey_07</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/grey_15</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/color_accent</item>
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimary'.

Comment: Why down vote? You need to define your own colors for "@color/color_primary". Or you use <item name="colorPrimary">#CCCCCC</item> or whatever color.

Comment: It needs to be declared in the themes section. Like in the other answer.

Comment: Sir i have updated an image to the question . Am i doing it wrong ?

Comment: Which compile and targetSdk you are using? Refer to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431676/appcompat-v721-0-0-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-attr-andro

Comment: Change it to at least 21.

Comment: No other way to programiticallt change that color

Comment: What i actually want to achieve is just change the highlighted color of listview.. I am able to do it in touch mode and set my custom color.  but in case when i call it programitically, it highlights in default blue color

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86948/discussion-between-tushar-narang-and-thomas-r).

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a listSelector on your listview:

```
<item name="android:listSelector">@color/yourColor</item>
```

But it is better to define a state drawable.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
<!-- Set AppCompat’s color theming attrs -->
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_color</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/my_darkercolor</item>

</style>
```

Comment: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimary'.

Comment: Make sure that you've downloaded the latest extras as well as the Android 5.0 SDK via the SDK-Manager

Comment: refer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23155637/change-background-color-of-the-action-bar-using-appcompat

Comment: If you are using AppCompat this will work for KitKat too. Do not forget to apply your theme in the manifest.

Comment: Any way to do it  without downloading

Comment: change minimum sdk version to ?