# Custom View with text view is not coming

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-custom-view, android-appcompat

I am inserting custom view inside a relative layout. The action bar turning into white color 
Here is the xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/dark_tablet_converted"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <com.test.myview
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="8dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="text : "
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is the image.

[image: TextView without custom view]

[image: CustomView with TextView]

I am not getting where is the problem.

Android support library used

```
'android support appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
'android.support v4:23.0.1'
targetSdkVersion 23
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
```

**EDIT:**
Whatever placed above my view will get displayed. only if any layout/view is placed below my customview will get vanished.

Comment: Okay . Package name com.test ??

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Yes . Problem is action bar getting white.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23155637/change-background-color-of-the-action-bar-using-appcompat

Comment: I see there are two issues actually. One that your action bar turned white, and the other that nothing placed below your custom view is getting displayed. Am I getting it right?

Answer (score 0):

your views are child of relative layout
so, they are drawed one on the other
and you can't really decide who will be in foreground and who will be in background

add a framelayout as parent of your custom and text view
then, in your code, find your textview and call "bringToFront"

Comment: Action bar getting white. How frame layout will solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/dark_tablet_converted"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <com.test.myview
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="8dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="text : "
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```