# Why am I getting Dark theme when I have declared it to be light?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-theme

I'm developing an app with material design.

I have added a toolbar to the activity & I have set it's theme to be light here: `app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"`, but still I'm getting a dark theme after running it.

**Here's my activity_about.xml file's code:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context="com.abc.xyz.AboutActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Here's AboutActivity.java file's code:**

```
public class AboutActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_about);

        SpannableString s = new SpannableString("About");
        s.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(this, "Pacifico.ttf"), 0, s.length(),
                Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(s);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_about, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**Here's styles.xml file's code:**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="MyMaterialTheme.Base">

    </style>

    <style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

I'm new to material design & hence don't know what to do.

Please let me know.

I'm new to StackOverflow, so please cooperate.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please check your _style.xml_ for your app theme!

Answer (score 0):

You have to change you xml ***AppTheme***.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.Material.Light.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
```

Comment: After changing the parent theme from `parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"` to `parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar"`. It reads: `"Cannot resolve symbol: parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar""`. What to do now?

Comment: check edits for more and also check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23155637/change-background-color-of-the-action-bar-using-appcompat)

Answer (score 0):

You have to make Toolbar theme in your xml file

In styles.xml

```
 <style name="ToolbarTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/seccolor</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/md_white_1000</item>
</style>
```

And Now In your Main xml File use it

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top" />
```

It should Work.

Answer (score 0):

The `app:popupTheme` attribute is for the menu popup, and all other popups that overlay the toolbar.

May be your toolbar is not getting themed because you haven't referenced the correct theme in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Make sure it is like this:

```
<manifest>
    <application
        ...
        android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme.Base">

        <activity/>
        ...

    </application>
</manifest>
```

That'll theme all the activities in your app. You can even apply it on individual activities.

Answer (score 0):

In your `styles.xml`

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

<style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="MyMaterialTheme.Base">

</style>

<style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

the parent of your main theme is

`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">`

also in your `MyMaterialTheme.Base` has parent as

`<style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">`

Removing the `.DarkActionBar` from both will help. Then you can probably add a style for your toolbar as mentioned in above answers.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was that I was not applying a theme for toolbar.

I fixed this by adding just this line: `android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"` to my toolbar widget in xml files.

Thanks all for your efforts!