# How to change the background of the Action Bar

Tags: android, image, action

How can I change the background of the action bar in my app to a image from the drawable folder? It would be nice if you could tell me in which code goes to which file.

Comment: have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23155637/change-background-color-of-the-action-bar-using-appcompat/23156002#23156002)

Answer (score 0):

Add this property in your toolbar:

```
 android:background="@drawable/yourImage"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set background of your action bar as simple as that:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/your_app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@drawable/your_drawable" />
```