# change color of android

Tags: android, colors, android-actionbar

I know this question must be asked before, but I don't know where can I find the solution since I don't know what is the name.

I want to change the color to red. How can I do to achieve this ?

[image]

Thanks a lot !

Comment: check if this [helps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23155637/change-background-color-of-the-action-bar-using-appcompat/23156002#23156002)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the color of the application bar (and the application's primary color – the application bar inherits it), just change your `colorPrimary` attribute. Like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/yourColorResource</item>
</style>
```

Instead of `@color/yourColorResource`, you can directly use a color's hexcode or Android's pre-defined resources such as `@android:color/holo_red_dark`

For the status bar's color, you can use similarly use the `colorPrimaryDark` attribute. You can read more about this [here](http://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html#ColorPalette).

Answer (score 1):

A style on Android contains a number of different attributes. This can control background color, text color, font styling, etc.

The `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` style contains several attributes for an overall light theme with a dark colored action bar.

If the background color you want to use needs white text and icons on top of it, you reference this as the parent and just change the background color.

`<item name="android:background">#ff0000</item>`

If your background color would look better with black (or dark) text, you could set the parent to `Theme.AppCompat.Light`.